# Sitecore TDS Deployment Property Setup Guide

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

We are using TDS 5.0 for Sitecore 7.2 solution.

Could you please help with best practices for following?

1. Which config to choose for Current Config?
2. Which Child Sync state to choose and for which items?
3. Which Deploy setting to choose for which items?

Basically I'm after best practices that has worked from your project experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The settings you choose for you TDS project setup will have a lot of what your solution is. The following are the best practices which I use:

**Current Config:**

This value is based off your build configurations. Typically you would have something like a Debug, Test, and Release configurations, where each configuration corresponds to different deployment environment (your test sever, production server, etc.) Set this setting for each item based on whether you want the item to be deployed in a particular configuration. E.g. use `Current Config - Exclude` to not include Test Data items in your Release/Production build.

**Child Sync state:**

The value you use will depend on what the item is and also the particular intentions of your solution.

For all your template items, it is best to make sure `Child Sync - All Children` is used, that why any template modifications you make will always be picked up when you perform a sync operation.

For items which under the content tree (/sitecore/Content), the value you use will vary based on the purpose of the item. If for example your site has a folder item for news items, then you would probably set the Child sync state for the News folder to be `Child Sync - No sync` as it is unlikely that any new items that you create in your development environment needs to be automatically synced into the project.

If you only need to sync the direct children of an item and not the children's children (descendants) then use the `Child Sync - Direct Descendants` option.

**Deploy:**

Use `Deploy - Once` for the majority of the items in your TDS project. This will tell the generated package to only deploy the item if it doesn't existing in the database it is being installed to. This means you can ensure that solution critical items are always present in your target environment, but if they have been modified already in the environment, the package will not overwrite the existing changes.

Such an example would be the Home Page item for the website. You would want to make sure it is always there, but will most likely have been modified by Content Authors between releases.

Use `Deploy - Always` if you want the package to always overwrite the existing item in the target environment with the values that you have in source control. It is probably best not to use this setting on any items that Content Authors will be editing, otherwise lose of data could occur making your Content Authors upset.

**Additional:**
I usually use `Deploy - Always` on my template items since the assumption is that the template items in source control are required to make the tested solution work. Therefore we want to override any changes made in the target environment to ensure we have a stable instance.

Comment: One standard practice I tend to follow is create multiple TDS projects per solution.  I will have a {ProjectName}.TDS.Master that will sync my Templates and Layouts, and a {ProjectName}.TDS.Content which will store my dummy/test content for development.

Sometimes I will put a content items that i want persisted (i.e. tags or overall site structure such as landing pages) in the TDS.Master and update the setting to Deploy - Once if I know business users will be making changes to the content directly in the deployed environment. Typically I do this because because of access rights.

Comment: Is there a way to set up the project so that there is a default option selected for any added items? I want to set all items in the content tree and media library to deploy once. If there isn't I think I'll just upload content as a package and set the content and media library nodes' current config to exclude for my delivery configuration.

Comment: It looks like any items added to the tds project inherit the same properties that their parents had

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't come across it, here is the official guide: http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#deployment_properties